# Identificação de aplicação na rede

Tags: php, javascript, android

Olá, eu estou a criar um sistema de leitura de código de barras em que tenho um aplicativo num dispositivo que serve de câmera, e manda essa informação para uma página web num PC. Mas eu cria fazer que a página fizesse uma busca na rede local do usuário e achasse o IP do dispositivo onde estaria a aplicação. Isso é possível fazer com JavaScript ou PHP? Se sim por favor digam o nome da tecnologia que se usa para eu pesquisar sobre esse assunto!

Comment: Poque não usar o java? Seu aplicativo é híbrido?

Comment: O aplicativo é desenvolvido no android studio e se for usar Java como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com android (java), você pode fazer isso:

```
public static String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        // gera uma lista enumerada de todas as interfaces de endereços de rede
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement(); // pega o elemento
            // gera uma nova lista com todos os endereços de IP da interface
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement(); // pega o endereço IP
                // verifica se este endereço não é um "localhost" e verifica se este é um IP de protocolo  IPv4 
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    // retorna o valor em string
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Esta função retorna o IP de protocolo de IPv4

Se você quiser o IPv6, deverá usar no seu if desta foma:

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address)
```

Ou assim, para pegar qualquer um dos dois:

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && (inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address || inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address))
```

E então você envia essa informação para o site. Melhor né?

Fontes:

**Documentação do Android**

- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface
- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress
- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet6Address
- https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Inet4Address

**StackOverflow**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064510/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-device-from-code/12449111#12449111